# How do I get from this stalactite to a blue figment in the Brain Tumbler Experiment?

Tags: psychonauts

I'm going through the Brain Tumbler Experiment level (for what's technically the second time) and there's a blue figment on a cliff that I can see off in the distance.

[image: view of figment from platform]

I am able to grip the stalactite and move around it to position myself, but I can't see where I'm supposed to jump to from here.

[image: hanging onto the stalactite]

When I go further around it, there are brambles preventing me from landing on the edge if I try to jump in that direction. The branches that are visible in the screenshot haven't let me stand on them at all over several attempts.

How can I get to that blue figment? I realize it's possible that I don't have the powers yet in order to do so, so if that is the case, what powers/PSI level do I need in order to reach it?

I'm currently Rank 32 and have access to Pyrokinesis, Telekinesis, Invisibility, and Marksmanship.

Comment: You'll probably need to revisit that when you can float (and then try jumping or floating over there). Can't confirm that since I don't have Psychonauts installed right now. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Come at it from the original direction (not from the back as you are trying to do).  You need to backtrack about one doublejump levitate leap to get to the higher shelf.  Once you're up there, proceed to the vertical vine.  There's a vine hanging across that you can swing on.  Orient facing before the jump - double jump to reduce lateral motion - try many times.

This fellow manages to do it: